# IOS app crash when messaging notification permission is prompted [IOS / ReactNative]

Tags: ios, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have implemented notification in react native using firebase messaging. When the application in installed, during the first launch of the application the crashes when asking for the notification display permission [just before the permission is being asked]. When testing without ios emulator once the app gets the notification permission / if the app is reopened again, the app opens just fine.

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0
```

Complete Crash log : https://pastebin.com/ttBBd2mK

Not sure what the issue is exactly here, any help is appreciated.

Note: Android works fine without issue, the only issue is with IOS.